# JavaScript class inheritance infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
function Person() {
  console.log('person');
}

function Player() {
  this.personConstructor();
}

Player.prototype = Person.prototype;
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
Player.prototype.personConstructor = Person.prototype.constructor;

new Player();
```

The intent is to inherit from `Person` into `Player` then have that new child class call the parent's original constructor. However, this causes an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong and why is the loop happening?

Comment: `Player.prototype = Person.prototype;` should be `Player.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`

Comment: ...this is because when you made `Player.prototype` a *reference* to `Person.prototype` and then assigned `Player` to `Player.prototype.constructor`, you were actually assigning it to `Person.prototype.constructor`. So then `personConstructor` was actually a reference to `Player` instead of `Person`, and so created the infinite call loop.

Answer (score 4):

This line right here is your problem:

```
Player.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

You want the prototype for `Player` to *inherit* from `Person`'s prototype, but **not** make them equal. Currently, your code makes the `Player` and `Person` prototypes *reference equal*, so any changes to `Player.prototype` also affect the `Person.prototype` (effectively making them indistinguishable).

You're looking for:

```
Player.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instantiates a new object with a given prototype *without* actually calling the constructor (unlike a regular `new Person()` call would do). This allows you to get a new object inheriting the `Person` prototype, which you can then modify for the specifics of a `Player`.

**EDIT**: As suggested in the comments by Siddarth, an even better solution would be to set the `constructor` through a [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Player.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {
    constructor: { value: Player }
});
```

This way, the newly created prototype will have its `constructor` property made non-configurable, non-enumerable and non-writable. This prevents you from accidentally changing it afterwards through an assignment (e.g. `Player.prototype.constructor = Foo`) and it won't show up in `Object.keys` or a `for..in` loop. Normally, this shouldn't matter much but it's a good practice.

Comment: I would make that Object.create(Person.prototype, { constructor: { value: Player } })

Comment: Also, don't forget to call the parent's constructor in the child's constructor.

Comment: @Siddharth Oh right, you can pass in a bunch of property descriptors to `Object.create`. I personally prefer using classical assignment or something like `_.extend` for adding properties to a prototype. Property descriptors may be better though, your solution prevents the prototype's `constructor` from (accidentally) getting changed later on. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(args) {
  console.log('person');
  args=args||{};
  this.name=args.name||"no name";
}

function Player(args) {
//  this.personConstructor();
// I prefer 
  Person.call(this,args);
}

Player.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;

console.log(new Player());
console.log(new Player({name:"Jon"}));
```

It may be better to just re use Parent constructor with the following

```
Person.call(this,args);
```

Because if you use something like `this.parent()...` you'll get an infinite loop when you inherit 3 levels deep.

More on prototype and constructor functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711).

Comment: `this.personConstructor()` works fine, no need for `.call` if you're going to pass in the same `this`. However, `Person.call(this,args)` is indeed a more general solution which doesn't need the extra `Player.prototype.personConstructor` definition.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Correct, I changed the answer.